# Como adicionar sistemas .asd no lisp/Windows7?

Tags: windows, allegro, lisp, brainfuck

Então galera, é o seguinte, estou tentando rodar um código que interpreta BRAINFUCK escrito em LISP, então encontrei esse git:

https://github.com/equwal/LispFuck

ele parece ser bem amigável e o melhor até então (os outros não consegui rodar, acho que por alguma besteira ou não entender o código).

Estou usando a plataforma Allegro 10.0, mas tenho outros compiladores de lisp instalados. O alegro já tem o ASDF na versão 3.16, porem quando tento instalar o sistema:

(asdf:load-system :brain)

Ele simplesmente não instala, fala que o componente não foi encontrado.
Fazendo umas pesquisas encontrei que o windows não cria links simbólicos (nem sei exatamente o que é), e que isso dificulta, eu preciso muito instalar esse .adb, me ajudem por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisa usar `(require :asdf)` no allegro, e também precisa põe o `LispFuck` no "ASDF load directory". Então consegue o `(asdf:load-system :brain)`.

Este programa está criado por mim.

Comment: Obrigado amigo!